# Meaning of the verb "recover" in context

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

It was in the 12th episode of the 9th season of *Friends*. Here is the [scene](https://youtu.be/xpJRGk-zdx0). It's at around 13 seconds.
Rachel: Yeah, I just get a little bummed when my birthday's over.

> Monica: Well, at least you have one thing to be happy about. That jerk
> Gavin from your office didn't show up (Gavin shows up at the balcony
> windows).
>
> Rachel: Mmm hmm.
>
> Gavin: Yeah, hey. (comes in to the balcony)
>
> Monica: Oh, we weren't talking about you. No, no way to **recover**.

I looked it up in this [dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/recover) and any of the definitions seem to fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Monica insulted Gavin and realized that he had heard her, she tried to make it sound like she didn't actually insult him by saying: "Oh, we weren't talking about you." But then she realizes it's obvious that she did in fact insult him. So there's no way of going back or in other words no way of recovering from that insult.

More generally speaking: When you do or say something that you would rather not have done or said you can try to recover from that something.

Comment: It might help to add that the second definition on the cited page does fit:  to return to a normal condition after a period of trouble or difficulty.  She realizes that she can't plausibly make it seem that her insult was about some other Gavin from the office.  She can't try some other way to recover from the embarrassment, after having started with an excuse that obviously won't work.  Her saying "nope, no way to recover" is much like admitting that she made a mistake that, now, she can't fix.